# Dynamically passing subscription key to a LuisDialog rather than an attribute

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to pass my subscription ID to a LUIS Dialog, rather than an attribute?

My application has this information on the database, and I need to pass it via a constructor, or another way.

Any sugestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **LuisDialog** has a constructor that takes a **LuisService**(s).  You can pass in a modelId and subscriptionId, and create the **LuisModelAttribute** dynamically:

```
public class LuisTestDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public LuisTestDialog(string modelId, string subscriptionId)
            : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(modelId, subscriptionId)))
        {

        }
    }
```